# Redux-form Field Array is not working as expected when wrapped in Tab component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I wanted to create a redux form similar to one as provided in this example
https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/ using Field Array.

But I wanted each member to be shown in a separate tab. I am using material-ui Tab component for this. Please refer this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jjy10p86n9 (This is just an example that I was trying but ultimately I want that clicking on add member button should add a new tab in the app bar with the new member fields)

The issues that I am facing is:

1. When I click submit button only fields in the current tab are validated. Fields in the other tabs are not validated.
2. When I switch between the tabs previous validations in the tab are removed.
3. If we visit the tabs for than once and hit the submit button, No validation errors will be shown.

Does anybody have any idea or suggestion how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to hide/show tab contents associated with a tab button rather than rendering tab contents when tab button is clicked.
So, the code sample you've got renders content for the selected tab with this code:

```
    {fields.map(
        (member, index) =>
          tabValue === index && (
            <div key={index}>
    ...
```

You want to create a css class that has "display:none" set, and apply this class to content that **isn't** related to your current content. For example:

```
   <div className={tabValue === index ? null: "hiddenClass"}>
    {fields.map(
        (member, index) =>
          (
            <div key={index}>
    ...
    </div>
```

Hope that helps!